# Delay and fade in text with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, delay, fadein, fade

There is a line in my page I want to delay 2 seconds and fade it in. Is there a way to do it without jQuery?

The site is
http://theclockpage.com/
And the text is the little line under the clock, the text is obtained through javascript that's why I don't add it to the question.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var textCont = document.getElementById('clock').nextSibling;
textCont.style.opacity = 0;

setTimeout(function() {
    var opacity = 0,
        animate = setInterval(function() {

            opacity += 0.05;

            if (opacity >= 1) {
                clearInterval(animate);
            }

            textCont.style.opacity = opacity;

        }, 10);
}, 2000);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/SRFqT/).

Comment: This function does not work. It will not properly cast the string to an integer to be added. textCont.style.opacity = '0'; and textCont.style.opacity = parseInt(textCont.style.opacity) + 0.05 + ''; will work.

Comment: @Greg The jsFiddle must be doing something funny then :P

Comment: More likely, your browser wasn't doing something funny. In google chrome and webkit, CSS Styles are strings, and must be used as strings.

Comment: @Greg They sure are. But I never read the `opacity` property back from the `style` object.

Comment: Yes, you do. opacity += 0.05; You also try to compare a string to an integer: opacity >= 1.

Comment: @Greg I *set* the `opacity` variable to `0`, which is a `Number`. There is also nothing wrong with comparing a string to an integer, the string will be [coerced to `Number`](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/uJLL2/).

Answer (score 0):

```
    var d = document.getElementById("box");

    function fadeOut(fadeScaler, hertz) {
        if (!this instanceof Element) return false;
        hertz = (!hertz) ? 60 : hertz; // Approx 60 hertz refresh rate

        var opacity = this.style.opacity
            opacity = "0";

        var t = setInterval(
           function() {
             opacity = parseInt(opacity) + fadeScaler + '';

             if (parseInt(opacity) >= 1) 
               clearInterval(t);
           },
           Math.floor(1000 / hertz)); // 1000 miliseconds / hertz = refresh rate
    };

fadeOut.apply(d, [.05]);
```

Id use this one, Alex's function will not work. Opacity is a string and cannot be +='d with an integer.

Comment: @alex That is the problem. opacity _is_ a string. In CSS and webkit anyways, so this function is cross-browser.

Comment: @Greg I set it as a `Number` `0`. I don't ever read the `opacity` property, just set it.

Comment: opacity += 0.05; // This is reading the opacity property. It is only short form for opacity = opacity + 0.05, it is not actually changed code.

Comment: @Greg No, that is reading the `opacity` variable. Do you see `with (textCont.style) { ... }` anywhere?

Comment: Lol, I did until you edited your question exactly 1 minute after I posted my answer.

Comment: @Greg [I added a link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5775361/revisions) to the jsFiddle in that edit.